# Why EF core tell me 'specified member is unmapped'?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I want to filter users by name and return a new DTO by using the projection query (by Select):

```
var result = context.Users
    .Where(user => user.FullName == search)
    .Select(u => new UserPagingViewModel
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        IsSearchable = u.IsSearchable,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        FullName = u.FullName,
        Photo200 = u.Photo200,
        City = u.City,
        About = u.About,
        Skills = u.UserSkills.Select(us => us.Skill.Name),
        IsTeamMember = u.UserTeams.Any(ut => ut.UserAction == UserActionEnum.JoinedTeam)
    })
    .ToList();
```

User class:

```
public class User : IHasId
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Telegram { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName + " " + LastName;
    public string Photo100 { get; set; }
    public string Photo200 { get; set; }
    public bool IsModerator { get; set; }
    public List<UserTeam> UserTeams { get; set; }
    public List<UserSkill> UserSkills { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Team> TeamsToRecruit { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool AnyTeamOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Data Base is `PostgreSql`. Data provider `PostgreSQL/Npgsql provider for Entity Framework Core`

But when I try to execute this request, I get an exception with the following message:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
> .Where(u => user.FullName == search)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'FullName' on entity type 'User'
> failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I don't want use client evaluation.
If I compare for example the FirstName property everything works fine.

Please help me figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: `FullName` is unmapped (and possibly other things), end of story... Either add them as a calculated fields in your db and add it to your model builder as such, or don't use it in queries

Comment: `FullName` is a computed `get` property, not a member of the database table itself, this means it can't be translated into a SQL query as the column, presumably, doesn't exist there. Either change the property to have a `get` and a `set`, or query by other columns that do exist in the database table.

Comment: In fact, instead of going down the rabbit hole I propose, just comment out this `// FullName = u.FullName,`

Comment: @00110001, Oh really there is no column in the table, everything turned out to be very simple :) Thank you so much!
but the option with commenting `// FullName = u.FullName` didn't work and I don't really understand why it should have worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have FullName in three places. Since you don't have a full name column (or computed column) you can't use that in dbcontext queries. It will generate sql like below.

```
SELECT FULLNAME,... FROM USERS WHERE FULLNAME = N"some value".
```

This is why you are getting an error.

You need to remove all FullName from dbcontext query and do where filter like below.

```
var result = context.Users
    .Where(x => (x.FirstName + " " + x.SecondName + " " + x.LastName) == search)
    .Select(u => new UserPagingViewModel
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        IsSearchable = u.IsSearchable,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        //FullName = u.FullName,
        Photo200 = u.Photo200,
        City = u.City,
        About = u.About,
        Skills = u.UserSkills.Select(us => us.Skill.Name),
        IsTeamMember = u.UserTeams.Any(ut => ut.UserAction == UserActionEnum.JoinedTeam)
    })
    .ToList();
```

This will you something like below

```
FROM [Users] AS [t]
WHERE ([t].[FirstName] + N' ' + [t].[SecondName] + N' ' + [t].[LastName]) = N'some value'
```

Then remove FullName from User object.

```
public class User : IHasId
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Telegram { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    // public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName + " " + LastName;
    public string Photo100 { get; set; }
    public string Photo200 { get; set; }
    public bool IsModerator { get; set; }
    public List<UserTeam> UserTeams { get; set; }
    public List<UserSkill> UserSkills { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Team> TeamsToRecruit { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool AnyTeamOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Add FullName to UserPagingViewModel.

```
public class UserPagingViewModel{
    ...
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {SecondName} {LastName}";
}
```

If you want FullName as part of user object, then add as notmapped or use [HasComputedColumnSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascomputedcolumnsql?view=efcore-5.0)

Comment: yeap the same error, this query still tries to execute on the DB side, and there is no FullName field

Comment: I think I overlooked your problem, I updated the answer.

Comment: This will be a terrible running query because it isn't a [sargable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)